# Stored function pointer of expired lambda works. Why?

Tags: c++

This lambda definition:

```
auto lambda = [](int i)->std::string {
    return std::to_string(i);
};
```

Is equivalent to this functor:

```
struct Lambda {
    std::string operator()(int i) { return std::to_string(i); }
};
```

Consider this class definition whose purpose is to hold a function pointer (not a std::function object):

```
struct Holder {
    using Callback = std::string(*)(int);

    void SetCallback(Callback cb) { mCallback = cb; }
    Callback GetCallback() const  { return mCallback; }

private:
    Callback mCallback;
};
```

Then, else where in code, a function stores an actual pointer in a Holder, followed by a use of the function callback:

```
void Store(Holder& holder) {
    auto toStr = [](int i)->std::string {
        return std::to_string(i);
    };

    holder.SetCallback(toStr);
}

void Transform(int i) {
    Holder h;
    Store(h);
    auto cb = h.GetCallback();
    std::cout << cb(42);      // Expected this to crash, but doesn't.
}
```

QUESTION:

Why doesn't `Transform` crash?

The `Store` function creates a local lambda, and then stores a pointer to it in Holder. Holder stores a pointer to the callback, not a std::function. Presumably, the `toStr` object goes out of scope at the end of `Scope`. When `Transform` gets the callback pointer `auto cb = h.GetCallback()`, isn't it getting a pointer to an expired object?

My test was done in MSVC 2022

Comment: When you decay a lambda into a function pointer the compiler stamps out a normal function for the pointer to point to.

Comment: Worth noting - _crashes_ are the result of Undefined Behavior, and you should not anticipate how Undefined Behavior behaves.

Comment: The question is if this is really UB because I would say that functions have no lifetime, so a function pointer can not expire.